# Scheduled task with a WMIC Script to close processes in a folder + copy folder

Tags: mysql, batch-file, cmd, wmic

I have a Windows batch script, which should close all applications in a folder, stop the MySQL Server, and copy the data folder to a backup folder.
When running it normally from a command prompt, it works perfectly, but when I run it as a scheduled task, it just closes the applications.

Here is the script:

```
net stop mysql5
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in (`
    wmic process  where 'CommandLine like "%%ProgramFolder%%" and not     CommandLine like "%%RuntimeBroker%%"'   get ProcessId  /format:value
    `) do (
    for /f "tokens=* delims=ProcessId=" %%# in ("%%a")  do (
        if "%%#" neq '' (
         taskkill /PID %%# /F
        )
    )
)
@echo on 
xcopy "C:\Program Files\MySQL\data\*.*" d:\backup\ /h/i/c/k/e/r/y
net start mysql5
```

Comment: If your intention is to backup your databases why not use mysqldump.exe? That way you don't have to kill/stop anything.

Comment: Compare the environment variables (use the SET command) when the script runs.  They need to be the same, assuming you are running both as same userid.

Comment: Also, verify what user account is used when the "task" runs. Does "task" mean the Windows Task Scheduler?

Comment: Is drive D: a mapped drive for a UNC path? If so try mapping it temporarily as the working directory (i.e. ".") via `pushd \\server\share\backup`. When done, unmap it via `popd`.